A functional that maps a differentiable function $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ to a closed loop in two dimensions
How do I describe a functional $f$ that maps a differentiable function $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ to a smooth $h: [0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ such that $h(0)=h(1)=g(0)$ with the remaining constraints described in English as follows, and pictorially below: $f$ should warp $g$ such that it becomes a closed loop while preserving $g$'s structure (not sure how to define this either, but intuitively it should preserve its local minima/maxima). For example, a constant function should warp into a circle. A cosine function should warp into a squiggly circle.
If this question is ill-defined, possibly due to insufficiently many constraints, please make and state assumptions as necessary.


Your two examples suggest something like $$Fg(x)=(g(x)\cos(2\pi x),g(x)\sin(2\pi x))$$ which wraps your function $g$ around a circle. This is linear and preserves regularity if you add the assumption that $g(0)=g(1)$. Is this what you’re after ?

@SimonPitte how did you arrive at that? asking to see if i can follow the same method to arrive at a solution that allows me to lift the assumption of g(0)=g(1)

I didn’t follow any method, I just generalised you example. You wanted a constant function to give you a circle (constant radius) and a sine function to give you oscillating radius…

@SimonPitte any idea how you can generalize it further to lift the g(0) = g(1) assumption :)?

Sure you could set $$Fg(x)=(g(2x)sin(x),g(2x)cos(x))$$ when $0\leq x\leq 1/2$, and  $$Fg(x)=(g(2-2x)sin(x),g(2-2x)cos(x))$$ when $1/2<x\leq 1$, but you’ll have no guarantee of regularity at $x=1/2$

another follow-up question: by "This is linear", you mean F is a linear functional, is that correct? i.e., $F(g+h) = Fg+Fh, aFg = Fag$

Yes that’s exactly what I mean. To me functional always means linear, as most of functional analysis is only concerned with linear functionals, which is why I remarked on it.

@SimonPitte thank you :)!

Ah! you're essentially applying Euler's formula and taking out the imaginary number in the first comment!
